# how to call functions inside xmlelement tag in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, nsxmlelement

I tried calling a function in following format and it did not work, is there a way to call a function inside xmlelement

```
SELECT
XMLElement(
            "routingentry"
            ,f_rout_en()
)FROM dual
```

Comment: Normally I do not think it should be a problem? What error do you get? What datatype does the function `f_rout_en()` return?

Comment: The Function returns XMLTYPE.
I get following errors

Error(1137,2): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(1145,6): PLS-00231: function 'f_rout_en' may not be used in SQL
Error(1145,6): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: Your function sounds like it is declared for example in a package body alone or in a declaration section? That's the meaning of "may not be used in SQL" - a function needs to be declared "publicly" in either package spec or as standalone function to be used inside a SQL statement. Otherwise the SQL engine does not know about the function, it becomes an invalid identifier as far as the SQL engine is concerned.